# Return the Sum() of a query, using LinQ and Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this generic method in my repository for searching

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Search(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{                
     return Dbset.Where(predicate);
}
```

And this one that searches all the Disable records of my entity

```
public IEnumerable<CodigosDeOperacao> GetDisabled()
{
     return Search(c => !c.Active && c.disabled).OrderBy(c=>c.Code);
}
```

I would like to return the number of disabled, because I will need to know if it equals zero.

So I created this method.

```
public CodigosDeOperacao GetTheAmmountOfDisable()
{
     //somthing like taht
     return Search(c=>c.Ativo).Sum();
}
```

How could I return these records using these methods using Lambda and LinQ?

Comment: what is `Buscar`? what you are trying to do here? Do you want **number of** `Buscar` which are active ?

Comment: if you want to know if the disabled elements are zero or nor , you can use linq function .Any(x => !x.Active)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar "Buscar " is the same as Search, I forgot to rename

Comment: @JordiJordi Good idea, had forgotten this method

Answer (score 1):

Use Count instead of Sum

```
public CodigosDeOperacao GetTheAmmountOfDisable()
{
    //somthing like taht
    return Search(c=>c.Ativo).Count();
}
```